# Audio and video out of sync when using mkvmerge

Tags: conversion, matroska

I extracted audio and video from an mkv using mkvextract. Then I used mkvmerge to merge them back into an mkv. When I played the mkv the audio and video were out of sync.

How can I combine them so that they are in sync? I tried to find some helpful information using mkvmerge on the original file to see if there was any useful information, but didn't find any.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple workflow:

- Find out how much out of sync it is with VLC player by using <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> buttons.
- Download `mkvtoolnix` and click on add file.
- Add your video file. When added, click on the audio file and now you can add your delay. Simply put, use - or + and which ever you delay worked out with vlc.
- Press `mux now`. Done :)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the original file specified an audio delay. If you're using the mkvmerge GUI, you can change the audio track's delay in the *Format specific options* tab.  Positive values delay the audio track, negative values advance it (all in milliseconds).  If you're using the command line, you need to use the `-y` or `--sync` arguments.  See [the mkvmerge documentation](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html) for details.  The documentation also shows you how to scale the audio delay evenly though out the video (instead of a set constant delay).

To determine the audio delay you need, you can use Media Player Classic along with the +/- keys to determine the delay.  Alternatively, you can try to use a media information tool to see what the delay was on the original file.

Comment: If there's a delay specified in the original file, shouldn't mkvinfo be able to display that?

Comment: @OSX Jedi Yes, but only if the delay was *after* the audio was encoded (and explicitly specified when the file was first mkvmerge'd).

Answer (score 1):

In commandline mkvmerge it's like this:

```
mkvmerge --verbose -o output.mkv  -y 1:1000 input.mkv
```

where

- 1 is the track number, you can find it out using `mkvinfo` or `mediainfo` (the latter adds 1 to the track number, ie. uses natural counting starting with 1). Most of the times it will be 1 for the first audio track.
- 1000 is the delay in MS (milliseconds), so 1000 is 1 second.

BTW, `--verbose` might help you in finding out what exactly is happening and why it's out of sync.

Comment: The delay is in milliseconds, not microseconds. 1000 milliseconds is one second. 1000 microseconds is 1 millisecond.

Comment: @DanielCassidy thanks, good find. fixed it. no idea how I made this mistake. :o)